# Python - for loop: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, typeerror

I am trying to use the code below to check if someone is allowed to ride a coaster. The first part is to create a 2D list and the second part is for the checking.

```
heights = [165, 154, 156, 143, 168, 170, 163, 153, 167]
ages = [18, 16, 11, 34, 25, 9, 32, 45, 23]

heights_and_ages = list(zip(heights, ages))
heights_and_ages = [list(info) for info in heights_and_ages]

can_ride_coaster = []
for info in heights_and_ages:
  for height, age in info:
    if height > 161 and age > 12:
      can_ride_coaster.append(info)
```

I get the error on the line 19

```
for height, age in info:
```

error is:

```
line 19, in <module>
    for height, age in info:

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

I think it's because I use two variables bcs it's alright if I use one, but after searching online that doesn't seem to be a problem. How can I fix this?

Comment: try using heights_and_ages = [[list(info)] for info in heights_and_ages]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be any need for a nested loop here. Each element of `heights_and_ages` is a pair, and you want to loop through it unpacking each pair into `height` and `age`.

```
for height, age in heights_and_ages:
    if height > 161 and age > 12:
        can_ride_coaster.append((height,age))
```

This lends itself to a list comprehension:

```
can_ride_coaster = [(h,a) for (h,a) in heights_and_ages if h > 161 and a > 12]
```

---

Why does your code error?

Suppose `info` is `[165, 18]`. When you write

```
for height, age in info:
```

you are saying "loop through `info` and unpack each element to `height, age`".

In the first iteration of that loop, the element is 165, and you try to unpack that single int value to multiple variables. That is why you get `int object is not iterable`.

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize that. Though, why would the original code produce such errors, if you don't mind me asking? started learning to code only 2 days ago, so would appreciate a response

Comment: I have added some more explanation to my answer.